# Graph the average for the day / multiple data daily - Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have 4 values collected daily.
I want to graph the average of the 4 values on a time series graph.

[image]

If I was to plot this.
1/03/2021 will show an average value of 15 and 2/03/2021 will show an average value of 35.

I tried using quick measure that says rolling average of 1 day before 0 days after, it gives me an error.

The Dax which I've tried didn't work either - getting "too many arguments were passed to the Values Function. the maximum argument count for the function is 1". This is me trying to follow some instructions online for the first time.

Day Avg = AVERAGEX(VALUES([Date], [Values]))

Thanks for the input.

Gem

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data looks like this

### Table

| Date | Time | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/03/2021 | 00:01:00 | 10 |
| 01/03/2021 | 06:00:00 | 20 |
| 01/03/2021 | 12:00:00 | 15 |
| 01/03/2021 | 18:00:00 | 15 |
| 02/03/2021 | 00:01:00 | 30 |
| 02/03/2021 | 06:00:00 | 20 |
| 02/03/2021 | 12:00:00 | 40 |
| 02/03/2021 | 18:00:00 | 50 |

It seems your row context is at the table level, so you don't need to use `VALUES`.

```
AVG =
AVERAGEX ( 'Table', 'Table'[Value] )
```